# How to enable auto-update feature for a self-hosted app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have hosted an android app on my own hosting site. The app is not published yet on Playstore. I need to enable the auto-update check feature. I am new to android development & don't know codes.

Example:
When the user opens the app, it has to check in the background, if any new updates are available. If  there are any new updates, it automatically show the update dialogue.

Please give me instructions with codes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to host the latest APK version on some server, as well as the latest version.

For example, you can check the latest version on the server, compare it to current version, and then prompt user to download new version if there is one.

You won't get the full working code since you have to do something by yourself.
You can ask what is not clear from the algorithm, I've proposed, and I'll explain.